# BehaviourSubject is emitting value only once

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I am learning rxjs and I guess I am doing something wrong as my BehaviourSubject is emitting value only once.

In my **Service** -

```
private cartItemCount = new BehaviorSubject<Observable<Number>>(this.getCartItemsCount());
actualCartItemCount=this.cartItemCount.getValue();

getCartItemsCount(){
return this.http.get<Number>('/api/getCartItemsCount/'+this.getCartID());
}
```

*Below Method is also in above service for Add or Remove Product but will be called from **ProductCartComponent** and inside I am calling Behaviour Subject next method*

```
private updateProductCart(cartID:string,productId:number,change:string){
this.cartItemCount.next(this.getCartItemsCount());
return this.http.get<Item>('api/updateProductItem/'+cartID+'/'+productId+'/'+change);
}
```

Now in my **NavBar Component** I am subscribing to **actualCartItemCount** Observable

```
constructor( private cartService:ShopingCartService)
 { }

ngOnInit() {
this.cartService.actualCartItemCount.
subscribe(res => {this.totalCartItemCount = res;
}
```

In the console I can see getCartItemsCount will be called whenever add or remove is happening but in NavBar Component where I have subscribed to the **actualCartItemCount** is being called only once.

Kindly guide me and let me know if more details are required on this...

Comment: My guess is that you have two different instances of the service. Show us how and where you have provided the service (i.e. where you have `providers: [ShopingCartService]`.

Comment: In app.module.ts i have the following array and all the services are mentioned like this - _providers: [SignUpService,
    **ShopingCartService**,
    AuthGuard,
    LoginGuard,{
    provide:HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass:AuthInterceptor,
    multi:true
  }],_

Comment: you might be destroying the `subscription` somewhere like in `ngDestroy` or something so that it is not getting

Comment: In `this.cartItemCount.getValue()` you have the returned value from `this.getCartItemsCount()` which is created only once. Then subscribing `this.cartService.actualCartItemCount` is subscribing to `this.http.get` and not the `BehaviorSubject`.

Comment: yes @martin you are correct...
i couldn't use _.asObservable_ on **this.cartItemCount** as it was already Observable<Number> so i went ahead with that..

Comment: @martin is there a way that changes made in 1 tab will reflect in another tab while observing an observable?

Answer (score 0):

First, read the [component interaction guide](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) thoroughly.

If NavBar is always there in the view you wouldn't require a BehaviorSubject, simple Subject can do.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class CartService {

  // Observable number sources
  private countSource = new Subject<number>();

  // Observable number streams
  count = this.countSource.asObservable();

  // Service message commands
  updateCount(count: number) {
    this.countSource.next(count);
  }
}
```

In NavBar you can use the observable directly in template using `async` pipe:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav-bar',
  template: `Count : {{cartService.count | async}}`
})
export class NavBarComponent {
  constructor(private cartService: CartService) {}
  }
```

In Product Cart, you can update the new count like shown below, it will update the value in NavBar, or any other places:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-cart',
  template: `
  `
})
export class ProductCartComponent {
  constructor(private cartService: CartService) {}
  /**
  Update count in the shared service and thus in NavBar
  */
  private updateCartCount(count: number){
     this.cartService.updateCount(count);
  }
  }
```

Comment: I want to update the count of the item in Shopping Cart in Navbar

Since Navbar and Product Cart components are not related component and I need to have an interaction between them whenever any product is added or removed from Cart.

Comment: You want Product Cart to send the `count` to navbar? Or just tell navbar that something is changed so that NavBar can fetch new data from server?

Comment: I want Product cart to send +1 or -1 to NavBar count in case of adding or removing product from cart respectively. But I am stuck there so went with the above approach of any update happened get count data from the server. I guess I need some more knowledge on sharing information b/w components.

Comment: i have completed it but didn't create extra Observable **count** from **countSource** and made some other changes!!! _**Final Query**_-  I have 2 tabs opened and changes in 1 tab are **not** reflected in other tab. Is there anything we can do to make it work??